# Generate random Maze in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-arrays, maze

as I wrote in the title I need to generate a random maze with some restrictions. I'm a newbie in C++, and I would like to ask if there's an efficient way to implement in C++. I would like to create a bidimensional array of ints ( every [x][y] would have either a WALL, PASSAGE or VISITED. I also would like to create the array dynamically j: create a maze with 80 rows and 30 columns. So I would like to create a vec[80][30]. In C is easy with malloc and using only memory needed.

Don't know if `std::vector` is useless or there's another instruction more suitable. I'd like to use a bidimensional array because is cleaner to read and more intuitive. I know I could use a 1D array instead.

The second question is that I want to generate and AddNodes (`addwalls`) to the maze until I can't put more or I reach a limit. So I don't know exactly how to express this. I would like to call `addnode` to a maze which initially it doesn't have any wall ( "empty maze") and begin to put walls on it.

Idea:

```
Maze maze; 
maze (80,30,50);
...
```

so from an empty 80x30 maze id began to add random walls till a limit is reached. I get a random node, I test if it is valid (it's on the limits and it's not a wall yet), and then I add it to the maze. If the maze is connected I continue with more nodes. If not I delete the node and continue. If I reach a limit of random nodes no valid then I stop. The result would be a connected maze with some random walls. I forgot to mention that walls have to be symmetric either vertical or horizontal. I need some help with general idea, because I know I have to read a lot of C++ syntax, although I've coded in Java for many months.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

#define PASSAGE 0
#define WALL 1
#define VISITED 2

#define NORTH 0
#define EAST 1
#define WEST 2
#define SOUTH 3


using namespace std;
// PODEMOS definir las direcciones tambien asi...

enum DIRECTION {
  NORTH = 0, EAST = 1, WEST = 2, SOUTH = 3
};

enum TYPE {
  PASSAGE = 0, WALL = 1, VISITED= 2
};

//http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/833/

class Maze { 
  private: 

    int nr; // number of rows
    int nc; // number of columns
    int complex; // complexity of the maze: how hard to leave
    vector< vector<int> > vec; //array bidimensional de enteros
    //vector de dos dimensiones
    /*vector<T> elems;     // elements 
     // Create
    vector< vector<int> > vec(4, vector<int>(4));
    // Write
    vec[2][3] = 10;
    // Read
    int a = vec[2][3];*/
  public: 

    void Maze();
    void Maze( int rows, int columns, int hard);
    void PrintMaze();
    void ShowMaze(vec);
    bool isConnected ();
    void explore (Node posicion);
    bool validMove( Node actual);
    Node RandomNode(); // Obtienes un nodo al azar valido
    Node MirrorNode (Node actual); //devuelve el nodo espejo/mirror de un nodo null en otro caso..
    void reverseExplore();
    int getnr();
    int getnc();
    int getComplex();
    void setnr();
    void setnc();
    void setComplex();
    } 
}; 
void Maze::Maze(void) {
         cout <<"No hace naA"<<"\n\n";
}
void Maze::Maze(int rows, int columns, int hard) {

    //Comprobar numer filas y columnas es par/impar y sino salir dando mensaje correspondiente
    /*
    if (nr %2) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: El numero de filas tiene que ser par/impar.\n");
        exit();
        return 101;
    } else if (nc % 2 != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: El numero de filas tiene que ser par/impar", nproc);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 102;
    }

    if (mr < 20 || nc < 10) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: El laberinto tiene que tener al menosu unas medidas\n");
        exit();
        return 103;
    }
*/
    nr=rows;
    nc=columns;
    hard=0;
    bool Final=false;
    Node actualNode;
    setupMaze();   //Inicializar laberinto ( todo a 0, poner los  bordes y casilla inicial)

    do {
        actualNode=randomNode();     //Obtengo un nodo aleatorio valido: que no sea pared y este en los limites
        addNode(actualNode); //Añado el nodo al laberinto
        if ( isConnected();) {
            //hard=0; //opcional para contar solo las veces que intenta en el  "mismo intento", ahora al colocar el nodo bien puedes inicializar los intentos a 0.
            cout << "\nInsercion correcta del nodo\n"; // compruebo si el laberinto es conexo o nodo
        }
        else {
            //Si laberinto resultante no es conexo, tengo que deshacer la inserción del nodoactual e incrementar el valor de hard
            deletenode( actualNode);
            hard++; 
        }
    while ( hard <= complex)

}
bool validMove( Node actual )
{
   // return x >= 0 && x < size && y >= 0 && y < size && maze[x][y] != '#';
    return actual.posx >= 0 && actual.posy < nc && actual.posy >= 0 && actual.posy < nr && vec[actual.posx][actual.posy] == 'PASSAGE';
    //FALTA or de la casilla inicial..
}

    bool coordsAreEdge( Node actual)
{
    return actual.getposx== 0 || actual.getposx== nc - 1 || actual.getposy == 0 || actual.getposy == nr - 1;
}
bool coordsAreEdge( int x, int y )
{
    return x== 0 || x== size - 1 || y == 0 || y== size - 1;
}

bool isConnected();
    {
        Nodo inicial;
        inicial.posx=0; ///inicial.setposx=0
        inicial.posy=1;// inicial.setposy=1
        explore(incial);
        // Si todos nodos son VISITED o WALL exceepto casilla inicial entonces connected es true ( hemos podido visitar todos los nodos pasillo)
        //en otro caso nos quedan nodos por visitar por tanto no es conexo
        reverseExplore();
    }

void explore(Nodo nodoPartida)
    {
    //punto de inicio:siempre el mismo o encontrar el primer 0 del vector

    vec[ nodoPartida.posx ][ nodoPartida.posy ] = 'VISITED';
    printMaze( maze );

    for ( int move = direction, count = 0; count < 4; count++, move++, move %=4 )
        { //seria mas facil pienso como arriba hacer un if para cada movimiento y no un for con los 4 movimientos...
            //int nextX; int nextY;
            switch ( move )
                {
                case WEST: nodoPartida.posx++; break;
                case NORTH: nodoPartida.posy++; break; 
                //nextX = x; nextY = y + 1; break;
                case EAST: nodoPartida.posx--; break;
                case SOUTH: nodoPartida.posy--; break;
                default: ;
                }
            if ( validMove( maze, nextX, nextY )) /// esto me mola mucho porque antes de mover como te dije antes verifica que el movimiento sera correcto
            {
                //Recursion move part 1
                mazeTraverse ( maze,  nextX ,  nextY, (move + 3)%4 ); //igual en vez de move se podria llamar de un if en cada direccion total son solo 4 posibilidades
                return;
            }
        }
void setupMaze(void) {

for ( int x = 0; x < nr; x++)
{
    for ( int y = 0; y < nc; y++)
        vec[x][y]='0';
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
cout << "\nHit return to see next move\n";
cin.get();
}

class Node{
     private: 

    int posx; // position x
    int posy; // position y

    public: 

    void Node();
    void Node( int x, int y);
    void PrintNode(Node x);
    void PrintNode(int x, int y);
    int getPosX();
    int getPosY();
    int setPosX();
    int setPosY();
//  bool validMove();
//  int setConplexetConplex();   
};
```

Any ideas or help would be apreciated.
Node would be a class with two members: posx and posy. I added the class node just to be cleaner and readable
The main question:
1 - How to declare and which instruction is more suitable for bidimensional array maze. If i use an int maze[int][ìnt]; would seem a C program. Also perhaps would be more elegant to make an array of nodes instead.
2 - How can i call functions of the maze as randomnode, addnode indeed the constructor of maze.
3 - Any other suggestion about this code which is an sketchy idea.

Comment: Search the internet and StackOverflow for "c++ maze generation" for examples.  Always search first before posting.

Comment: ive done it, but my implementation has some restrictions and i need to make it elegant, polite and efficient. Ive concrete problems that dont appear in searching... i need help answering my previous three questions... Thanks for your help